# Applet does not display, but no errors either

Tags: java, swing, applet, awt

I am trying to create this program for my class project. The compiler says process completed but nothing shows up when I try to run it.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Project extends Applet implements ActionListener {

    Label sp = new Label("Receipt Calculator");
    Panel pl = new Panel();
    Label cndy = new Label("Candy:");
    TextField cndyi = new TextField(5);
    Label bred = new Label("Bread:");
    TextField bredi = new TextField(5);
    Label sop = new Label("Soap:");
    TextField sopi = new TextField(5);
    Label mlk = new Label("Milk:");
    TextField mlki = new TextField(5);
    Label ham = new Label("Ham:");
    TextField hami = new TextField(5);
    Label srdns = new Label("Sardines:");
    TextField srdnsi = new TextField(5);
    Label cfee = new Label("Coffee:");
    TextField cfeei = new TextField(5);
    Label ndls = new Label("Noodles:");
    TextField ndlsi = new TextField(5);
    Label salt = new Label("Salt:");
    TextField salti = new TextField(5);
    Label btrs = new Label("Batteries:");
    TextField btrsi = new TextField(5);
    Button co = new Button("Compute Price");
    Panel pnl = new Panel();
    Label st = new Label("");
    Label tx = new Label("");
    Label t = new Label("");

    public void init() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        setBackground(Color.blue);

        add(sp);
        add(pl);

        pl.setLayout(new GridLayout(11, 2));

        pl.add(cndy);
        pl.add(cndyi);
        pl.add(bred);
        pl.add(bredi);
        pl.add(sop);
        pl.add(sopi);
        pl.add(mlk);
        pl.add(mlki);
        pl.add(ham);
        pl.add(hami);
        pl.add(srdns);
        pl.add(srdnsi);
        pl.add(cfee);
        pl.add(cfeei);
        pl.add(ndls);
        pl.add(ndlsi);
        pl.add(salt);
        pl.add(salti);
        pl.add(btrs);
        pl.add(btrsi);
        add(co);
        co.addActionListener(this);
        add(pnl);
        pnl.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2));
        pnl.add(st);
        pnl.add(tx);
        pnl.add(t);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent z) {
        int a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j;
        double nst, ntx, nt;
        a = Integer.parseInt(cndyi.getText());
        b = Integer.parseInt(bredi.getText());
        c = Integer.parseInt(sopi.getText());
        d = Integer.parseInt(mlki.getText());
        e = Integer.parseInt(hami.getText());
        f = Integer.parseInt(srdnsi.getText());
        g = Integer.parseInt(cfeei.getText());
        h = Integer.parseInt(ndlsi.getText());
        i = Integer.parseInt(salti.getText());
        j = Integer.parseInt(btrsi.getText());

        nst = (a * 31.50) + (b * 35) + (c * 25) + 
              (d * 38.85) + (e * 43.15) + (f * 13) + 
              (g * 39) + (h * 7) + (i * 10) + (j * 30);
        ntx = nst + (nst * .12);

        nt = nst + ntx;
        st.setText("Sub-total = " + nst);
        tx.setText("Sub-total = " + ntx);
        t.setText("Sub-total = " + nt);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Project();
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you executing this? Extending Applet would suggest it to be run as an Applet but you have a `main()` method that essentially does nothing. Also, are you forced to use AWT components instead of Swing components?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put all the panels in a Frame. Try to use this tutorial.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html  This is the Window used to display all the things, and make them visible.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a homework question to me. Problem is that you have nothing to run.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Project();
}
```

All that does is make a new object but after that the program terminates: you need a loop.

Try this tutorial: [Building Your First Java Applet](http://java.about.com/od/webapplications/ss/firstapplet.htm).

Answer (score 0):

> Nothing shows up when I try to run it

That's because you haven't asked for anything. `new Project()` only creates a `Project` object and since you don't have a default constructor defined and you aren't explicitly calling any other methods, execution exits immediately. Make the following change

`new Project().init();`

You need to place your `Panel` in a `JFrame` to make it visible. Try something like the following in your `init()` method

`JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.add(pl);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);`

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs fine for me.  I see:

[image]

My guess is that you are trying to run it as a Java Application, instead of as a Java Applet.  You do have `main()` method in your class, which is what might be causing this confusion.  `main()` can be removed.  In the case of applets, `init()` is the entry point, like `main()` would be if it was run as a application.

Right-click on the class and select Run As > Java Applet.  For example:

[image]

Comment: I am using JCreator. How do I do this in JCreator?

Comment: @user3464914 Sorry, I assumed you were using Eclipse.  I've never used JCreator.  [This link](http://ngemu.com/threads/how-to-run-java-applet-in-jcreator.57636/) suggests JCreator cannot run applets.